# How to configure File[] on Maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven plugin that expects `File[]` for one of its config parameters (docs: [maven-failsafeplugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html#summaryFiles)). How do you configure such parameter in pom.xml? Ideally, I would like to say "include all files in directory X" or "my-test-output/*.xml".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
          <summaryFile>path/to/file</summaryFile>
          <summaryFile>path/to/file2</summaryFile>
          <summaryFile>...</summaryFile>
        </configuration>
    <execution/>
    <execution>
        ....
    <execution/>
</executions>
```

Look at the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) for more info and samples

Comment: Any hope for wildcard? It does not seem to work, I was wondering if there is some special element I could nest that does scanning and filtering.

Comment: According to the plugin source code can not use patterns for summaryfile, for includes only.

Answer (score 1):

The `File[]` should be reflected by some collection type element in which you can nest.

For example *summaryFiles*:

```
<summaryFiles>
    <summaryFile>/topping/*.xml</pizza>
    <summaryFile>/topping/special/cheese.xml</pizza>
</summaryFiles>
```